# auto-create symlink to currently inserted DVD

Tags: macos, dvd, applescript

Is it possible to use applescript or a shell script to automatically create a reference to the currently inserted DVD? If I pop out Midsomer Murders DVD and insert Star Trek, the Wrath of Khan, the path changes from, for example /Volumes/MM_SET_17_DISC_1 to /Volumes/ST2_DISC1

Finder supports launching an applescript when a disc is inserted, so I want to auto symlink the volume name to something like /Volumes/DVDFOLDER

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noticed, the volume name displayed by OS X changes with every DVD you insert, which makes symlinking to it moot. However, at the lower level of BSD devices, the DVD drive has a handle independent of volume names – [its filename in the `/dev` pseudo-filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file), where you will find all your drives as `/dev/disk#` (for the root disk level) and `/dev/disk#s#` (for the disk partition level) – “#” being a digit.

OS X provides the [`diskutil` utility](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8) to handle drives via the their device filenames. Insert a DVD and do

```
diskutil list
```

to find out which device filename your DVD drive has (for the sake of this example, let’s say it’s `disk3`). Once you know that,

```
diskutil info disk3
```

will show you all information about the disk – notably its Volume Name and, better even, its full Mount Point path, which you can extract with a regex and pipe into `ln`:

```
ln -fhs "$(diskutil info disk3 | sed -Ene 's#[[:space:]]*Mount Point:[[:space:]]+(/Volumes/.+)#\1#p)" /path/to/DVD
```

will get you a symlink to the DVD volume called “DVD” in `/path/to`. You can wrap that into an AppleScript or maybe AppleScript or Automator application and set it to run whenever a new video DVD is inserted (note this will leave you with an invalid symlink when you eject the disc).